# RPi + motion, bad video

Tags: raspbian, video, webcam

I use RPi with WIFI module for stream & webcam Creative LIVE! CAM Sync HD.
I use SSH, put 'sudo motion -s' in command line and create moving in front of camera. 
Here is a log: pastebin.com/5S2SDa2w

At the output I get the video, that does not play in my computer. But when i upload this video on vk.com, i see that video is bad. There is a lost frames and strange noise.

Here is a content of file [motion.conf](http://pastebin.com/Ar2KFXgb), and the [videofile](http://dfiles.ru/files/ce0dfwkzk)

It is interesting that after 1-2 seconds after starting move in front of camera - the command line stops for a few seconds, as if freezes, and go on.

Anybody help to solve this problem. Hope its possible..

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. The problem went away when I lowered the image widths and heights (must be multiples of 16), say 128x80. Then I raised these values until the problem reoccurred. You can also try to lower the framerate. Hope it works for you too.